# Vuejs, what does ':' and '@' mean in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vuejs, and I would like to know what ':' and '@' does in the context of this code?

I am unsure about if this the initial values for the module.

Thanks for any help.

Here is the code:

```
<appWindow
  :app="activeApp"
  :active="windowActive"
  @closed="windowActive = false"
  @removeApp="removeApp"
  @resetNotes="resetNotes"
  @updateCheckbox="updateCheckbox"
/>
```

Comment: They're shorthands for `v-bind:` and `v-on:` respectively: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand

Comment: Thanks for that, and linking the documentation! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `@` is synonymous to `v-on:`

It is used to handle Event
For more: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

```html
<!-- these two are same -->
<button v-on:click="foo()">Button</button>
<button @click="foo()">Button</button>
```

## `:` is synonymous to `v-bind:`

It is used to binding value to an attribute
For more: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

```html
<!-- these two are same -->
<img v-bind:src="imgurl">
<img :src="imgurl">
```

Answer (score 2):

The @ is shorthand for v-on

A : on a prop will make the contents evaluate as javascript rather than a string.